# Convert list of edges to adjacency matrix

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe represents a list of edges of a graph and has the following format:

```
  node1 node2 weight
0     a     c      1
1     b     c      2
2     d     c      3
```

My goal is to generate the equivalent adjacency matrix:

```
    a b c d
a   0 0 1 0
b   0 0 2 0
c   0 0 0 3
d   0 0 0 0
```

At the moment, while constructing the the dataframe of edges I count the number of nodes and create an NxN data frame and fill in the values manually. what is the pandas way of generating the second dataframe from the first one?

Answer (score 4):

Use `pivot` with `reindex`

```
In [20]: vals = np.unique(df[['node1', 'node2']])

In [21]: df.pivot(index='node1', columns='node2', values='weight'
                  ).reindex(columns=vals, index=vals, fill_value=0)
Out[21]:
node2  a  b  c  d
node1
a      0  0  1  0
b      0  0  2  0
c      0  0  0  0
d      0  0  3  0
```

Or use `set_index` and `unstack`

```
In [27]: (df.set_index(['node1', 'node2'])['weight'].unstack()
            .reindex(columns=vals, index=vals, fill_value=0))
Out[27]:
node2  a  b  c  d
node1
a      0  0  1  0
b      0  0  2  0
c      0  0  0  0
d      0  0  3  0
```

Answer (score 3):

Decided to have a little fun with the problem.

You can convert `node1` and `node2` to Categorical dtype and then use `groupby`.

```
from functools import partial

vals = np.unique(df[['node1', 'node2']])
p = partial(pd.Categorical, categories=vals) 
df['node1'], df['node2'] = p(df['node1']), p(df['node2'])

(df.groupby(['node1', 'node2'])
   .first()
   .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
   .weight
   .unstack())

node2  a  b  c  d
node1            
a      0  0  1  0
b      0  0  2  0
c      0  0  0  0
d      0  0  3  0
```

---

Another option is setting the underlying array values directly.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(0, index=vals, columns=vals)
f = df2.index.get_indexer
df2.values[f(df.node1), f(df.node2)] = df.weight.values

print(df2)
   a  b  c  d
a  0  0  1  0
b  0  0  2  0
c  0  0  0  0
d  0  0  3  0
```